# How to put part of my Controller logic outside my Controller? (one "big" service or multiple services)

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks, silex

Maybe it's a trivial question but I'm beginner with Silex and I don't know how to do it...so here is my situation :

I have a Silex app, everything works but I'm not a big fan of my Controller because there is a lot of code and I reapeat this code two times :

First controller :

```
$app->match('/', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
    // 1/ I get data from a form
    // 2/ I check if User is logged
    // 2.1 / If not logged -> I created new User (Entity User) + send email
    // 3/ I create a new Event (Entity Event) + put some file on AWS s3
    // 4/ I create a new Product (Entity Product)
    // 5/ I activate some add-on to my Event (request to an other BDD)

    return $app['twig']->render('home.html.twig');

})->bind('home');
```

Second controller

```
$app->match('/manage-my-product', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
    if ($app['security.authorization_checker']->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {

    // 1/ I get data from a form
    // 2/ If user is here he must be logged so no need to check one more time
    // 3/ I create a new Event (Entity Event) + put some file on AWS s3
    // 4/ I create a new Product (Entity Product)
    // 5/ I activate some add-on to my Event (request to an other BDD)

    } else {
        return $app->redirect($app["url_generator"]->generate("login"));
    }
})->bind('product');
```

As you can see I do almost the same with few difference, so my question : <del>Is to possible to put that logic outside the Controller and use it twice?</del> **How should I put that logic outside my Controller?**

I don't really know how to do it because I have lot of different things inside :

- I use 3 Entity that use 1 database connection (User, Event, Product)
- Those Entities works the same : I have one `Class Name` with the attributes + getter / setter, one `Class NameDAO` where I have all my methods (`findByEmail($email), find($id), ...`) that extends an `abstract DAO class` (my database connection + one abstract method to return a `Class Name`)
- Each `Class NameDAO` have a dedicated service (eg. `$app['dao.user']`)
- I use an other database connection to activate the add-on
- I use AWS s3 Class to put file on a server

**EDIT :**

According to the anwser I get I think my question wasn't very clear about my real problem...I had the intuition I need to use Service but I have trouble to build it so :

- Should I build ONE big Service that uses multiple services?
  OR
- Should I build one service by question and repeat my logic in both my Controller?

As I said before, I already have services `$app['user.dao']` and `$app['event.dao']` for example that I use to create a new User or a new Event for example, so should I do :

```
$app->match('/', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
    // 1/ Service 1 to create new user
    // 2/ Service 2 to create new event
    // 3/ Service 3 to create new add-on
    // and so on...

    return $app['twig']->render('home.html.twig');

})->bind('home');
```

OR

```
$app->match('/', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
    // Use ONE big service that use all the services I need

    return $app['twig']->render('home.html.twig');

})->bind('home');
```

**END EDIT**

As I said it works right now, but I'd like to know if it's possible to mix all this inside one method / function / service that I could use multiple time, could be nice for my future app !

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Services which you add to the Service Container as documented here:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container

(check the Symfony version that you are using)

Comment: I am using Silex as I said, is it the same? I know a little about Service in Symfony but Silex is the same?

Comment: Right. Slightly different. Here you go: https://silex.symfony.com/doc/2.0/services.html#service-definitions

Comment: Ok ty, my question was bad I guess because I knew this documentation and I was almost sure I need to use Service, I just have trouble to build a service using that much element (multiple Entities, multiple database connection, AWS s3 class,...)...

Comment: Your anwser is right so I upvote it, but it's not what I really wanted to ask so I edited my question if you want to edit your anwser

Comment: You service may inject other services which is a good practice. Code repeating is a bad practice. So write as many services as you like and inject them in new services when needed.